# How to download Nuget packages referenced by project from PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, github-actions

I'm creating *.yml* that automatically builds .NET Framework applications in GitHub Action.

So, I try to build .NET Framework 4.7.2 Application via Msbuild.exe inside Powershell.

like this:

```
PS : & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:myProject /p:Configuration=Release
```

However, you can see the following errors, and you cannot download the packages.

> error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
> this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
> information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
> missing file is
> ..\packages\MaterialDesignThemes.4.5.0\build\MaterialDesignThemes.targets.

How can I download the package that I need to build from Powershell through msbuild.exe?

(The dotnet CLI is not available because of the .NET Framework.)

Thanks!

++
Visual Studio builds normally. What I want is a script that is built automatically for the CI/CD pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I can use the nuget CLI instead of the dotnet CLI.

- nuget CLI : CLI tool for .NET Framework libraries and for any non-SDK-style project such as one that targets .NET Standard libraries.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference)

Solution :

1. Download the nuget CLI
2. `PS : nuget restore`

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-visual-studio here are all the ways.

If nothing helps you can try installing the packages manually using:

```
Install-Package <Package Name>
```